# Binding to custom .framework

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind to BugSense's lib but having a hard time trying to include the framework using `-gcc_flags` in the extra build arguments. BugSense provides a .framework and not a static .a lib. No amount of googling lead me to a solution to how to properly link the framework to my project.

So far I have something like this:

```
-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-framework ${ProjectDir}/../References/BugSense-iOS.framework"
```

I had copied the .framework folder to my References folder.

Building the project results in this mtouch error:

```
Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message:
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m: In function 'main':
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m:1838: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_enable_debug_tracking'
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m:1921: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mini_get_debug_options'
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m:1925: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_debugger_agent_parse_options'
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m:2059: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/var/folders/XV/XVCgAKTfGEmAUQGlxdGm9E+++TU/-Tmp-/tmp36ed5372.tmp/main.m:2059: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
ld: framework not found /Users/xxx/Projects/myProj/myProj/../References/BugSense-iOS.framework
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. If you succeed binding BugSense to Monotouch, would you share the solution? I'm trying myself, but it isn't working. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its like libraries: you specify the name of the framework and then specify where to search.

```
-F <dir>
-framework <name>
```

So try this:

```
-gcc_flags "-F ${ProjectDir}/../References -framework BugSense-IOS"
```

Comment: Thanks. In addition to your answer I found that you have to wrap the classes in that framework into your own static lib and then bind to those wrappers via the normal btouch bindings.

Comment: BugSense provides a static library target in its source code now. I was asked by @ayoung to disable THUMB for this, but you easily remove this flag (in "Other C Flags", delete the -mno-thumb flag).